# Индивидуальный дизайн для каждого браузера

Tags: html, css

На моём сайте http://ingsh.ucoz.ru когда вход через Оперу почему-то нижняя панель(доллары в длину нарисованы) под главным изображением сайта либо вытягивается вниз, либо просто делает большой отступ от него, что образует большое пустое пространство.

Проблему эту решить можно подставив в css этому диву параметр margin-top: -30px; но если я так и поставлю, то оно вконец испортит дизайн на других браузерах, что делать, можно ли как-нибудь через JavaScript для Оперы отдельный див сделать?

Comment: Учитесь верстать кросплатформенно, без костылей.  
А насчет костыля на js - я приводил пример вчера в одной из тем.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно воспользоваться так называемыми "хаками". Это блоки css, которые воспринимаются только каким-то браузером (не только Operой).
Напишите следующее в файле css:

```
@media all and (min-width: 0px) {
    #element { margin-top: -30px; }
}
```

Теперь тэг с id element будет выше на 30px, но только в опере!

Comment: Плохо, что только такой сайт уже не пройдёт валидацию, но, думаю, это не большой минус.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно создаю JS скрипт. Далее подключаю его к странице, а в нём подключаю отдельные css файлы, чтобы у всех браузеров были свои данные. Вот к примеру для всех браузеров один стиль, а для оперы - отдельный (где будут Ваши fix классы).

```
function init_fixed() {
    //opera
    if(window.opera) {
        document.write('файл css');
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в скобках после init_fixed что надо писать?
Этот див называется у меня bottom_panel, необходимо его для отключить для оперы и поставить другой bottom_panel_opera